# MsSQL convert string to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, rounding

Why in MsSQL some milliseconds are rounded to next?
For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2006-04-25 15:50:59.996', 120)
```

Produces

```
2006-04-25 15:50:59.997
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MS SQL server [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) values has certain accuracy.

They rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.

If you need more precision (and you're running at least SQL Server 2008) - use [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) type, it has accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.